# Configure Shibboleth native Service Provider and Apache

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth

I have a simple web application. I want to set Shibboleth native SP in front of my web app so that it issues/asserts SAML related things and forwards request to my web app. Is there a complete tutorial how to achieve that?

Comment: What web technology used, platform and framework may help.(Java/ PHP), os (Windows/Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

Use [testshib](http://testshib.org) to test your app, it gives too much ease.

Follow the steps

1. download and instal sp on your machine
2. include shibboleth's configuration into your apache 
   2.1. into httpd.conf file add include "PATH/opt/path/etc/apache22"(if  version is apache2.2, otherwise appropriate)
3. in apache22.config file add the location you want to secure - it would be /secure  bydefault
4. in your shibboleth2.xml file (in etc folder) put your entity id(application defaults element), ex https://mywebsite.com/shibboleth - this can be anything, not neccessary a real path
5. put entity id of your idp in sso element, in case of testshib it would be https://idp.testshib.org/idp/shibboleth
6. in the metadata provider put idp's metadata uri to your idp's metadata urn, incase testshib it would be http://www.testshib.org/metadata/testshib-providers.xml
7. Download your metadata from https://mywebsitehost.com/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata - here mywebsitehost would be a real host and rest path will be automatically configured by shibboleth - this path will download your sp's metadata file
8. Upload your metadata file to testshib via register

You are ready to go. Go to https://mywebsitehost.com/secure and you should be redirected to idp to authenticate.

**NOTE**: Make sure you have a domain name configured with ssl(https)